# I can't insert sql result from a connection to another

Tags: python, mysql, sql, insert, mariadb

I retrieved sql result from a query.

> coding: cp1252 -*-
> import pyodbc
> import mariadb
> .
> .
> cnxn=pyodbc.connect(...
> cursor=cnxn.cursor()
> cursor.execute("select cli, lib from ficcli")
> result=cursor.fetchmany(3)

then

> cnxn2=mariadb.connect(...
> .
> .
> mySql_insert_query = "INSERT INTO sxfcli (cli,lib) values(?,?);"
> cursor2=cnxn2.cursor()
> cursor2.executemany(mySql_insert_query,result)
> cnxn2.commit()

I have an arror message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#42>", line 1, in <module>
cursor2.executemany(mySql_insert_query,test_result[0])
File "C:\Users\alain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mariadb\cursors.py", line 350, in executemany
self._parse_execute(statement, parameters[0], is_bulk=True)
File "C:\Users\alain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mariadb\cursors.py", line 218, in _parse_execute
self._check_execute_params()
File "C:\Users\alain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mariadb\cursors.py", line 147, in _check_execute_params
raise mariadb.ProgrammingError("Data argument must be "
mariadb.ProgrammingError: Data argument must be Tuple or List
```

I checked

```
type(result)
                                   
<class 'list'>
```

result

```
[('totoco ', ' toto limited          ')]
```

If I create a list

```
test=[]
test=[('totoco ', ' toto limited          ')]
```

and i execute

```
cursor2.executemany(mySqlinsert_query,test]
cnxn2.commit()
```

it works

if I try

```
result==test
```

False

How can I do to make it work?

Comment: First question, does `test == test`? Second question, what does the structure of `result` look like?

Comment: No. I append values in test

result looks like a list. it looks like exactly like test

Answer (score 0):

execute_many() requires as second parameter a sequence of parameters which is usally an array (list) of tuples.

Contrary to what you described, the exception says that you are passing a tuple to executemany() instead of a sequence of tuples:

`File "<pyshell#42>", line 1, in <module> cursor2.executemany(mySql_insert_query,test_result[0])`

1. You don't pass `result` as a parameter
2. If test_result is a sequence of tuples, you pass the first element which is a tuple instead of sequence of tuples.

Comment: Hi Georges.
Thanks for your comment. 
In fact I've already tried a few things
The message error above was another test
and I've tried to pass a list of tuples, and only one tuple
I've even tried the function list(result)
I've the same error message